# what event get's fired when data has been entered in the cell in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

As the title suggests what event gets fired when the user has entered text in a cell. I wan't to use this event for handling some validation.

So far i am using `CellValidating` event but the problem with it is that it also gets called whenever the user clicks in the cell. Where as i want an event that only gets called once the data has been entered so i can perform validation.

```
private void totalPurchaseDataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex==0)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT id from Customer", connection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ad.Fill(dt);
            int value = int.Parse(e.FormattedValue.ToString());
            DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("id = " + value);
            if (!dr.Any())
            {
                totalPurchaseDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "Foreign key problem";
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            Form2 second = new Form2();
            this.AddOwnedForm(second);
            second.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for all available events and their description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try datagridview cellendedit event

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex==0)
       {
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT id from Customer", connection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ad.Fill(dt);
        int value = int.Parse(e.FormattedValue.ToString());
        DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("id = " + value);
        if (!dr.Any())
        {
              message.show("Foreign key problem");
         }
        else {
        Form2 second = new Form2();
        this.AddOwnedForm(second);
        second.Show();
         }
        }    

}
```

Comment: Problem with CellEndEdit is that i can't get the value of the cell like in the above code where i use `e.FormattedValue.ToString()`

Comment: e.FormattedValue.ToString() cell current value ?

Comment: dataGridView1 .CurrentCell .Value  - to get currentcell value or dataGridView1 .Rows[e.RowIndex ].Cells [e.ColumnIndex ].Value

Comment: Ok now there is another problem. In my code if validation failed i simply called `e.cancel=true` to stop making changes to the underlying data. However in this event the Eventargs doesn't have a cancel property so how can i cancel the changes made if they are not valid.

Comment: I Understand but is there any way to cancel the event so the underlying doesn't get modified in case of failed validation.

Comment: I think it's no way you may search in net to find